# run-parts with and without "--lsbsysinit" to update motd

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, motd

I am trying to edit my `motd`, so I kept to the best practice described in the `man` pages ([update-motd - dynamic MOTD generation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/update-motd.5.html) )

I added my script to `/etc/update-motd.d/`, named it `20-HDD-info` and made it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
DISKUSAGE=$(df |egrep "sda1|sdb1|sdc1")

echo "$DISKUSAGE"
```

So it is very simple, but still not working with `update-motd`

I dug deep into how `update-motd` works and found out, that it uses the command `run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d` to update the motd.

And this command suddenly worked, when I discarded the option `--lsbsysinit`

So my question is, why? And how can i repair my system so that it works with the `update-motd` command?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: ... I suspect it will work if you change the script name to all lower case i.e. `20-hdd-info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man run-parts`. It says, in part:

```
   If  the  --lsbsysinit option is given, then the names must not end in .dpkg-old  or .dpkg-dist or .dpkg-new or .dpkg-tmp, and must belong to one or more of the following
   namespaces: the LANANA-assigned namespace (^[a-z0-9]+$); the LSB hierarchical and reserved namespaces (^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$); and the Debian cron  script  names‐
   pace (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$).
```

Comment: Doesn't the OP's name choice satisfy the last of these though?

Comment: To summarize it. I am not allowed to use uppercase letters in the files name. So i changed `20-HDD-info` to `20-hdd-info` and it worked. Thanks.